# Boundary of a bounded open set under an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire and $B \subset \mathbb C$. Let $Bd( B)$ denote the boundary of $B$.
What you can conclude about $f(Bd( B))$ and $Bd(f(B))$, where $B$ is open and bounded. Is there any result available in case of unbounded sets?